# mongodb connect locally to vps database

Tags: mongodb

I am having problem connecting locally to mongodb on my vps. Vps has installed ubuntu 14. These are the steps ive taken:

1. commented out rule in `/etc/mongod.conf`

   - `#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1`
   - restarted mongo process `service mongod restart`
2. added rule to firewall so it accepts connection:

   - `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 27017 -j ACCEPT`
3. created user in mongodb:

   ```
   use admin
   db.createUser({
       user: 'myuser',
       pwd: 'mypassword',
       roles: ['userAdminAnyDatabase', 'dbAdminAnyDatabase']
   })
   ```

I read an article which stated that if you create user with above method it will be admin user for all databases, but in reality i can only connect to `admin` db successfully. If i try to connect to other `mydb` database it throws error `Authorization fails`.

this connect works:

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://myuser:mypassword@myip:27017/admin',function(err, db) {
```

this one doesnt:

```
mongo.connect('mongodb://myuser:mypassword@myip:27017/mydb',function(err, db) {
```

How can i add user to mongo so it will allow to connect with `mydb`?

Comment: You might actually want to read the "roles" page again, since the `*AdminAnyDataBase` roles do allow "adminstration" functions ( such as granting permissions ) but not really anything else. So your "application" really wants a "readWrite" or similar, and it also wants to know which database namespace you are giving it permission to. The currently applied roles use no database namespace and therefore really only apply any access to the "admin" database which keeps account information. So if you want different access, then you actually need to set that up. Presently you have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i just studied and tested some solutions, this one solves the problem:

```
use mydb
db.createUser({ user: 'myuser', pwd: 'mypassword', roles: ['readWrite'] })
```

after creating user with above syntax it works as expected.